# How do I embed php code that loads the image path to the database into my code?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a form that loads information into a database and then displays it (first code). Then I decided to modernize the code, and add the ability to upload a file (image) to a folder and add a path to the database, and then display the image in the same place as before (second code). But I don't have enough knowledge on how to properly pair these two codes for it to work. I also need to load two images into the database, but when help me how to do that with one image, I think I can figure out how to load two myself. This is my first project, I will be grateful for any help in resolving the question.

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
$msg = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    $photo = isset($_POST['photo']) ? $_POST['photo'] : '';
    $photo_xs = isset($_POST['photo_xs']) ? $_POST['photo_xs'] : '';
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
    $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO gallery VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute([$id, $photo, $photo_xs, $title, $content]);
    $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($result > 0) {
            $msg = 'Success';
        } else {
            $msg =  'Error';
        }
}
?>

<?=template_header('Create')?>

<div class="content update">
    <h2>Create photocard</h2>
    <form action="gallery_create.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="auto" id="id">
        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-select" name="photo" id="ref" required>
        <label for="photo_xs">Preview</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-select_xs" name="photo_xs" id="ref_xs" required>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required>
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    <?php if ($msg): ?>
    <p><?=$msg?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    
    $target_dir = "../img/images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    $imageExt = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $allowd_file_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    if (!file_exists($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"])) {
            $msg = 'Select an image to upload';
     } else if (!in_array($imageExt, $allowd_file_ext)) {
            $msg = 'Error. Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png.';         
     } else if ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 2097152) {
            $msg = 'Error. Size';
     } else if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $msg = 'Error. Name';
     } else {
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (ref) VALUES ('$target_file')";
             $stmt = $pdo->prepare("$sql");
              if($stmt->execute()){
                $msg = 'Success';                
              }
         } else {
            $msg = 'Error';
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't you just add the upload code to your existing code and then just add another field to your SQL? Either way, this kind of question is rather off topic for Stack Overflow as questions here must be focused on one problem, either upload or update.

Comment: If done stupidly ctrl-c ctrl-v, it doesn't work, that's the point. I don't know how to insert it correctly to make it work.

Comment: Didn't completely understand what your problem is or what you want to achieve. Looks like you want to upload file and also update its reference(file name) in DB. But looking at first set of your code, you should use `multipart/form-data` in your form and also the file input will be accessible via `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Comment: I need to replace a line of code          $photo = isset($_POST['photo']) ? $_POST['photo'] : '';         with the second code provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is almost ready, it just needs a few tweaks:

```php
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
$msg = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
    $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';

    $target_dir = "../img/images/";
    $filename = time() . "-" . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $filename;

    $imageExt = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $allowd_file_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    if (!file_exists($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"])) {
            $msg = 'Select an image to upload';
    } else if (!in_array($imageExt, $allowd_file_ext)) {
            $msg = 'Error. Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png.';         
    } else if ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 2097152) {
            $msg = 'Error. Size';
    } else if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $msg = 'Error. Name';
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO gallery VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $stmt = $pdo->execute([$id, $filename, $photo_xs, $title, $content]);
            $result = $stmt->rowCount();
            if ($result > 0) {
                $msg = 'Success';
            } else {
                $msg =  'Internal Error.';
            }
        } else {
            $msg = 'Internal Error.';
        }
    }

    $stmt = 
    $stmt->execute([$id, $photo, $photo_xs, $title, $content]);
}
?>

<?=template_header('Create')?>

<div class="content update">
    <h2>Create photocard</h2>
    <form action="gallery_create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="auto" id="id">
        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-select" name="photo" id="ref" required>
        <label for="photo_xs">Preview</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file-select_xs" name="photo_xs" id="ref_xs" required>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required>
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    <?php if ($msg): ?>
    <p><?=$msg?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

What I've done here is:

- Added timestamp to filename to allow upload of multiple equally named images.
- Fixed the query after the uploaded file is moved to the permanent directory.
- Added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that was missing, as pointed out in the comments.

Notice that once these changes are applied, there is still missing validation for the preview image. You should consider adding validation for `$_FILES["photo_xs"]` and only running the INSERT statement after both pictures have been uploaded successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already figured out my mistakes and rewrote this code to make it work.

Comment: @Sasha glad to hear it, hope I was somewhat helpful.